# 500 Internal Server Error - Log Location?

Tags: php, apache, internal-server-error

I'm running a Linux server with cPanel installed.

I keep getting a 500 error when visiting a certain page, but I'm trying to find the logs that can provide me with more information.

Here's one place I've found some logs for it:

```
/usr/local/apache/domlogs/mydomain.com
```

But all that has is generic information stating that a 500 error occurred, but not necessarily what caused it.  Where should I be looking for that information?

Comment: the apache error logs default to `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Aside from that, check out your httpd.conf (apache config) and that will tell you where your logs are being written.

Comment: Have you looked at the cPanel documentation for where cPanel keeps the logs? Doesn't it have a built-in log viewer?

Comment: cPanel does have a built in log viewer, but all it is stating is that the error occurred, not anything related to what caused it.  I'm checking with their support staff about it right now though.

Comment: I'm using MAMP and errors located here `/Applications/MAMP/logs`

Answer (score 8):

Running Apache2 in a CentOS, you can check the logs with the following command:

```
tail /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
```